# How to move tr by parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having second table constructions:

```
<div id="divThings">
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr><td><div id="someId">...</div></td></tr>
         ...
         ...
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

As a result my table looks like

```
------
test
test2
test3
test4
------
```

What I wanted to do is by using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   ...
   ...
});
```

move values in some divs so they will have a headers:
for example:

```
------
**Header 1**
test2
test3
**Header 2**
test
test4
------
```

Id for `<div>` inside `<td>` are generated. Or is it possible to use some different param?

How can I accomplish that?

**EDIT**

I **didn't** said that I have some jquery to execude (I said "what I wanted to do is by using"), because I am not sure how it even supposed to look (how should I get to table values and move them).

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Try preparing a *fiddle*, and tell us what's wrong

Comment: It sounds like your query isn't getting executed, is that it?

Comment: A bunch of downvodes, and no one even readed question properly... nice

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your 'divThings' to be present always and I have written the jquery code to add headers without using any generated ID's

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#divThings').find('table tbody tr').each(function(index){

$(this).find('td div').text('---Header' + index+'---');
});

});

Comment: As I understand this will add header for each div in table. Not what I am traing to do. I am trying to add header for a group of divs in table.

Comment: where the Div's will be located in DOM. If you can give the HTML I can modify the code accordingly.